# Array-like data structure efficient in terms of insert & find time

Tags: ruby, performance, data-structures

I need a data structure, implemented in `Ruby` language, to house a huge amount of distinct urls (e.g. `10**10` pieces), so the performance is my concern. 
I am using an `Array` and keep its elements ordered, so I can perform `binary search` to find if one already exists or where to insert a url rapidly.
I wrote this:

```
class UrlStore
    def initialize(*args)
        @urls = []
        args.each { |e| add(e) unless e.class != String }
    end

    def add(url)
        p = find(url)
        @urls.insert(p, url) unless p.class == String
    end


    def find(url)
        l, m, h = 0, 0, @urls.size - 1

        while l <= h do
            m = l + (h - l) / 2
            b = url <=> @urls[m]
            if b == 0
                return m.to_s
            elsif b == 1
                l = m + 1
            else
                h = m - 1
            end
        end

        return l
    end
end
```

The `find` method will, if found, return the position of the url in hosting array, but in `String` form in order to distinguish from those positions found to be inserted; Otherwise, return an integer(`Fixnum`) telling where the url should go to keep the array ordered.

But note that, I use `Array#insert` to add an element at a specified position. My intuition tells me that this method will move all elements after insert-point a step backward, which may cause severe performance deduction. The `Array` module is not in the standard library, its Ruby's intrinsic data type, so I don't know if I am right.

May be it's so naive a data structure for hosting such a task.
So can any one share an awesome one.

Comment: Let's assume 40 bytes per URL on average. With 1e10 URLs, that's over 370 GB of memory needed to store the information. Clearly you don't have the RAM for this, so clearly you need a database.

Comment: In any case, binary search is not the way to go. Hash lookup is what you'd use if you could (see the Set solution)

Comment: Arrays are great for queues and stacks, where you sequentially add and remove elements, but they really break down when you have to search a large array. Hashes are much better when you are randomly accessing an element, or need to check for its existence. When you are pushing the limits of your memory you need to look into offloading the lookup and storage to a database. At a minimum a key/value store, or something like SQLite will help. I prefer Postgres or MySQL because they're very smart and offer lots of useful features as the app's needs grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as Phrogz has suggested you do manage to get 370GB of memory, or you realise you don't actually need to store that many URLs, you might want to look into using a [SortedSet](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/SortedSet.html).

Comment: Or a simple `Set`. A `SortedSet` is never faster than a `Set`; it has an extra guarantee that's not needed here.

Comment: In the question the requirement is that the elements are kept ordered.

Comment: From the OP, I gathered that the elements are kept ordered *so he can perform a binary search*. Using hash lookup (which `Set` and `OrderedSet` use) is superior to binary search, so order is no longer a requirement.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: Thanks, I will do a compare on these.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, yes good point - my brain filtered that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the growing number of Open source NoSQL solutions including MongoDB, Cassandra, Kyoto Cabinet or Redis.

MongoHQ provides a free hosting service for MongoDB. RedisToGo provides a free hosting service for Redis. Both have very easy to use Ruby bindings. I have used both and recommend them.

I have heard good things about Cassandra and Kyoto Cabinet but have not used them in any production app.

Comment: Yes, Nosql are responsible for quick query. But I want to complete a whole task in a reasonable time, not just a single query/insertion. That means to count the communication(http request) time in, so if not using local Nosql there will be a heavy HTTP connection burden. Indeed, what I want is to accomplish all this in a commercial machine.  Hence, a good data structure needed. Don't care the number `10**10`, I just want to describe the task load, maybe I have no concept on quantities:), 10 Million is enough in my case. Thanks a lot.